# jQuery change script from another script

Tags: php, jquery

This could be a newbie question, but here it goes. I have the following script in a file where I cannot make any changes.

```
$('.btn-group label:not(.active)').click(function()
{
    var label = $(this);
    var input = $('#' + label.attr('for'));

    if (!input.prop('checked')) {
        label.closest('.btn-group').find('label').removeClass('active btn-success btn-danger btn-primary');
        if (input.val() == '') {
            label.addClass('active btn-primary');
        } else if (input.val() == 0) {
            label.addClass('active btn-danger');
        } else {
            label.addClass('active btn-success');
        }
        input.prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

but I need to make a simple modification on it. Is there a way from another script (in another file) change the above one to look like this

```
$('.btn-group label:not(.active)').click(function()
{
    var label = $(this);
    var input = $('#' + label.attr('for'));

    if (!input.prop('checked')) {
        label.closest('.btn-group').find('label').removeClass('active btn-success btn-danger btn-primary');
        if (input.val() == '') {
            label.addClass('active btn-primary');
        } else if (input.val() == 0) {
            label.addClass('active btn-danger');
        } else {
            label.addClass('active btn-success');
        }
        input.prop('checked', true);
        input.trigger('change');          // Added line
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just bind a new handler:

```
$('.btn-group label:not(.active)').click(function()
{
    $('#' + label.attr('for') + ':not(:checked)').trigger('change');
});
```

Beware, if class `active` can switch, to handle this change, you should delegate event:

```
$('.btn-group').on('click', 'label:not(.active)', function(){...});
```

Comment: I told you this was a newbie question :) Tried the second approach and worked like a charm. Thank you very much ;)